# Multi level html drop-down from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am new in XML and java script. I want to create nested drop-down that takes text from XML  using java script.so, whenever user  hover on any sub-menu then all options for that particular sub-menu will displayed in another multilevel drop down list.Photo given bellow.Image given below:
[image]

Here is My code:

```js
function createSelect(id, className) {
    return $('<select>').attr("id", id).attr("class", className);
}

function appendDropDown(id, text, value, classAttr) {
    $('<option>').val(value).text(text).appendTo(id);
}

var xml = '<root><sheet id="1" name="Submenu1"><row id="1_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="1_2"><col1>46.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="2" name="Submenu2"><row id="2_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="2_2"><col1>R2</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="3"  name="Submenu3"><row id="3_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="3_2"><col1>21.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet>></root>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find('sheet').each(function() {
    var sheet = $(this);
    var submenuName = $(sheet).attr("name");
    var submenuOptionIdentifier = submenuName + "option";

    //Adding options to Select Tag for Submenus     
    appendDropDown("#subMenuList", submenuName, submenuOptionIdentifier, submenuName);

    //Creating Select Tag for showing options for the submenus
    $("#optionsList").append(createSelect(submenuOptionIdentifier, "hide submenuOptions"));

    //Iterating over each and every row to get the options for the respective submenus     
    $(sheet).find('row').each(function() {
        var option = $(this).find('col2').text();
        var value = $(this).find('col1').text();
        appendDropDown("#" + submenuOptionIdentifier, option, value, submenuOptionIdentifier);
    });
});

//Showing respective options of the submenu on changing any options
$("#subMenuList").change(function() {
    $(".submenuOptions").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).css("display", "block");
}).trigger("change");
```

```css
.hide
{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
<select id="subMenuList"></select>
<div id="optionsList"></div>
</div>
```

Please let me know for further information. Thanks.

Comment: which part of your code are you having an issue with?

Comment: Thanks  @JaromandaX . Actually I want  that,whenever user hover on any particular sub-menu ,then options for only that sub menu will appear on different drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have nested dropdowns using the following code.

**CSS Code**

```
<style>
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.dropdown {
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.dropdown ul {
    box-shadow: -5px 10px 10px #888888;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown .menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 120px;
}
.menu .submenu > * {
    display: none;
}
.menu .submenu:hover > .menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0%;
}
.dropdown .menu li:hover {
    background-color: #6699FF;
}
.dropdown a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.button {
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown .selected-dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown-container" >
<a id="dropdown"  class="dropdown-click button" >
                Dropdown Menu <span class="arrow-down"></span>
 </a>
<div class="selected-dropdown">
</div>            
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {



    var xml = '<root><sheet id="1" name="Submenu1"><row id="1_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="1_2"><col1>46.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="2" name="Submenu2"><row id="2_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="2_2"><col1>R2</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="3"  name="Submenu3"><row id="3_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="3_2"><col1>21.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet>></root>',

        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);



    var dropdown = $("#dropdown-container");
    var menu = $("<ul />").attr('class', 'menu');

    $xml.find('sheet').each(function() {
        var sheet = $(this);
        var menuName = $(sheet).attr("name");

        var submenu = $("<li/>").attr("class", "submenu").text(menuName);
        menu.append(submenu);


        var childMenu = $("<ul />").attr('class', 'menu');
        $(sheet).find('row').each(function() {
            var option = $(this).find('col2').text();
            var value = $(this).find('col1').text();
            childMenu.append($("<li />").attr('class', "submenu").attr('data-value', value).text(option));

        });

        submenu.append(childMenu);
        menu.append(submenu);



        $(dropdown).append(menu);
    });



    $(".dropdown-click").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent(".dropdown").children(".menu").toggle();
    });


    $("#dropdown-container .menu li").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var thisObj = $(this);
        if (thisObj.attr("data-value")) {
            var selectedText = thisObj.text() + " : " + thisObj.attr("data-value");
            $("#dropdown-container .selected-dropdown").text(selectedText);

            $("#dropdown-container").attr("data-value", thisObj.attr("data-value"));

            /*You can also get the value of selected value of the dropdown in the future using                  $("#dropdown-container").attr("data-value");
             */
        }

        $(".dropdown").children(".menu").hide();


    });


    //For closing the menu if clicked outside the menu container
    $("html").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown").children(".menu").hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

Here is my JSFiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/oj8f2rwz/

Comment: Thank you so much @user3165829.It working great.Thank you again for staying with that post.

Comment: hello @Kamal, is it possible to make the drop down button as select tag.it will then simpler for me to fetch the value and send it to $_POST[] variables.Thanks

Comment: @user5005768 it is not possible directly. You will not get the same Look and feel of that UI. But we can tweak it by creating hiding the select menu and attach event handler so that any change in that dropdown li tag will inturn change the select tag.

Comment: @user5005768 I have added another answer for easy retrieval getting the selected value of the dropdown without using select tag itself. Can you check it out and tell me that what you have needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing every options available in the xml. You are only parsing the last element of the row options. You need to proceed like.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<select id="subMenuList"></select>
<div id="optionsList"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide
{
display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function createSelect(id,className)
    {
    return $('<select>').attr("id",id).attr("class",className);
    }
    function appendDropDown(id,text,value,classAttr)
    {
    $('<option>').val(value).text(text).appendTo(id);
    }

    var xml = '<root><sheet id="1" name="Submenu1"><row id="1_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="1_2"><col1>46.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="2" name="Submenu2"><row id="2_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="2_2"><col1>R2</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="3"  name="Submenu3"><row id="3_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="3_2"><col1>21.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet>></root>',

    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);


    $xml.find('sheet').each(function() {
      var sheet = $(this);
      var submenuName=$(sheet).attr("name");
      var submenuOptionIdentifier=submenuName+"option";

        //Adding options to Select Tag for Submenus 

appendDropDown("#subMenuList",submenuName,submenuOptionIdentifier,submenuName);



          //Creating Select Tag for showing options for the submenus
          $("#optionsList").append(createSelect(submenuOptionIdentifier,"hide submenuOptions"));

          //Iterating over each and every row to get the options for the respective submenus     
          $(sheet).find('row').each(function() {
             var option = $(this).find('col2').text();
             var value = $(this).find('col1').text();
             appendDropDown("#"+submenuOptionIdentifier,option,value,submenuOptionIdentifier);

          });


    });

    //Showing respective options of the submenu on changing any options
    $( "#subMenuList" ).change(function() {
          $(".submenuOptions").hide();
          $("#"+$(this).val()).css("display","block");   
   }).trigger("change");



    </script>
```

Here is my Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/wbz5xx03/

Comment: Thanks @user3165829, .its almost close,i just updated my code snippet by following your  code.it is still not working.can you please check my code snippet.Thanks

Comment: Sorry one of the line appendDropDown("#subMenuList",submenuName,submenuOptionIdentifier,submenuName) is commented out by mistake while editing...Can you recheck please?

Comment: I have also added a Fiddle Link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @user3165829, It is started working.its almost close.i can see you make separate drop down, not like nested.I mean if i hover on the submenu2 then another drop down will created.like this one [http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3 ] let know for any more info.thanks

Comment: I have added another new answer . Please check it out and tell me whether you are expecting nested dropdown provided in my new answer. Thanks..

Comment: yes  @user3165829 this what i was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom jquery plugin for your requirements.

**Function for parsing given XML:**

```
var xml = '<root><sheet id="1" name="Submenu1"><row id="1_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="1_2"><col1>46.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="2" name="Submenu2"><row id="2_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="2_2"><col1>R2</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet><sheet id="3"  name="Submenu3"><row id="3_1"><col1>CODE</col1><col2>Option NAME 1</col2></row><row id="3_2"><col1>21.0</col1><col2>Option NAME 2</col2></row></sheet>></root>';


function parseXMLData(xml) {
    var dataObj = {};
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);

    var arr = [];
    $xml.find('sheet').each(function() {
        var sheet = $(this);
        var menuName = $(sheet).attr("name");

        var obj = {};
        obj["name"] = menuName;
        var childrenArr = [];

        $(sheet).find('row').each(function() {
            var childrenObj = {};
            childrenObj["name"] = $(this).find('col2').text();
            childrenObj["value"] = $(this).find('col1').text();
            childrenArr.push(childrenObj);
        });
        obj["children"] = childrenArr;
        arr.push(obj);
    });
    dataObj["menu"] = arr;
    return dataObj;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<input id="dropdown-selector"/>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
 $("#dropdown-selector").dropdown({
        "menu": parseXMLData(xml)["menu"],
        "name": "Drop Down Menu"
    });
```

You can get the value of the selected dropdown value in normal way in jquery like

```
$("#dropdown-selector").val();
```

I have added the css and js file in GITHUB for making use of this custom jquery plugin.

Here is the github link https://github.com/kamalsomu/jquery-dropdown .

Include the jquery-dropdown.css and jquery-dropdown.js file in github to make it work.